# ho to print or export the dates for the values indicated by the arrows

Tags: amibroker

for the code at http://read.pudn.com/downloads160/sourcecode/math/719693/Exploration/Gordon%20Rose%20(617).afl__.htm

how to get the dates where the red  arrow i.e higher highs and green arrow i.e low lows to be displayed /listed in interpretation window or to export it to csv

Answer (score 0):

Code is not available. Kindly post here.

By the way, you can add filter = your condition; in your code and then explore using exploration.

https://www.amibroker.com/guide/h_exploration.html
For your help.

Then you can explore your result in csv from file menu.